# KOMA-Script and \captionformat

Tags: floats, captions, koma-script, french

I am using the class `scrartcl` to set an article which includes figures. I want the figures to have arbitrary titles, without a "Figure n:" in front of them. According to the KOMA-Script manual, I should put

```
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
```

in the preamble. This gets rid of the "Figure n", but the colon remains. I am surprised, because a year ago, I set a book using the `scrbook` class and used these lines in the preamble to get rid of the "Figure n:" and it worked. Now, however, several distribution updates later, if i rerun PDFLaTeX, the colons reappear. I am using koma-script 2016-122.3.20. I tried uninstalling and re-installing koma-script, to no avail.

Perhaps something else I am doing is interfering. Here is the entire preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[french,swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=tryonce,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.2}

\newenvironment{filmography}{\begin{description}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus 0.5ex minus 0ex}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0ex}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0ex plus 0.5ex minus 0ex}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1pc}
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pc}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pc}
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pc}}{\end{description}}

\usepackage[notes,strict,backend=biber,%
bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{hedling-bib.bib}

\begin{document}
```

The commands I am using to make the figure (at simplest--I often have to use minipages to put more than one figure together) are as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics{Hedling01}
 \caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
```

(Hedling01 is a jpeg.) As you can see, I am really trying to get the figure captioned "Figure n" with no colon (I don't want a figure list and I am not going to change the figures, so I don't need the automatic numbering). If there is some other way of doing this it would solve my immediate problem.

Comment: Please always show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of code snippets only. It would help us to do the same tests like you and so to reproduce the problem, analyze it and find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

`frenchb.ldf`, the French language definition of `babel`, does redefine `\captionformat` with `\AtBeginDocument`. It does so without testing whether or not the user already has changed the default definition. So you have to delay your own redefinition with `\AtBeginDocument` too (and have to do this after loading `babel`):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[frenchb,swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=tryonce,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}%
}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.2}

\newenvironment{filmography}{\begin{description}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus 0.5ex minus 0ex}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0ex}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0ex plus 0.5ex minus 0ex}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1pc}
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pc}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pc}
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pc}}{\end{description}}

\usepackage[notes,strict,backend=biber,%
bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{hedling-bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics{example-image}
 \caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note, I've used your code to generate a working example. But most of this code is not necessary to generate a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics{example-image}
 \caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce your issue even if I use KOMA-Script version 3.20 (2016/05/10):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
\begin{document}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]